# use joins in zend framework query

Tags: zend-framework, join

I want to use joins in zend. Below is my query

```
 $select = $this->_db->select()
 ->from(array('evaluationcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderevaluationcriteria'),
 array('ScoringCriteriaID','ScoringCriteriaWeight'))
 ->join(array('scoringcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderscoringcriteria'),
                               'scoringcriteria.    TenderId=evaluationcriteria.TenderId')
 ->join(array('tenderapplications' => 'procurement_tbltenderapplications','tendersupplier' => 'tblsupplier'),
                               'tenderapplications. TenderInvitationContractorID=tendersupplier.UserID');
```

I have UserID in tendersupplier table. but its giving following error :-

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tendersupplier.UserID' in 'on clause

Comment: it looks like you aliased `tendersupplier` as `tblsupplier`.

Answer (score 0):

The where condition is not written the way you did .

I dount that tblsupplier is a table then it should be in an array

This code is not tested!

```
   $select = $this->_db->select()
   ->from(array('evaluationcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderevaluationcriteria'),
    array('ScoringCriteriaID','ScoringCriteriaWeight'))
   ->join(array('scoringcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderscoringcriteria'),
                           'scoringcriteria.    TenderId=evaluationcriteria.TenderId')
    ->join(array('tenderapplications' =>  'procurement_tbltenderapplications'), array('tendersupplier' => 'tblsupplier'))
    ->where('tenderapplications. TenderInvitationContractorID=tendersupplier.UserID');
```

Comment: its giving error ---> Missing argument 2 for Zend_Db_Select::join().Its giving error on last join

Comment: @Nacdeep, is tblsupplier a table? I doubt it's a table, I update the answer

Comment: yeah, its an table. Now its giving error --->  Unknown column 'tendersupplier.UserID' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

> I think its not the right way to include more than one tale in same array of a join.
>   Try code like this..

```
->from(array('evaluationcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderevaluationcriteria'),
       array('ScoringCriteriaID','ScoringCriteriaWeight'))
->join(array('scoringcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderscoringcriteria'),
      'scoringcriteria.    TenderId=evaluationcriteria.TenderId')
      'scoringcriteria.    TenderId=evaluationcriteria.TenderId')
->join(array('tenderapplications' => 'procurement_tbltenderapplications'),
      'tenderapplications.TenderInvitationContractorID=tblsupplier.UserID');
```

> I am not sure whether you are planning to join values from tblsupplier table also.

Comment: its giving error ----------  Unknown column 'tendersupplier.UserID'

Comment: @Navdeep: Please recheck whether you are using tblsupplier.UserID' or tendersupplier.UserID. You must use tblsupplier.UserID.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to join 2 tables in one ->join, I don't think you can do that.

join code from Zend_Db_Select()

```
/**
     * Adds a JOIN table and columns to the query.
     *
     * The $name and $cols parameters follow the same logic
     * as described in the from() method.
     *
     * @param  array|string|Zend_Db_Expr $name The table name.
     * @param  string $cond Join on this condition.
     * @param  array|string $cols The columns to select from the joined table.
     * @param  string $schema The database name to specify, if any.
     * @return Zend_Db_Select This Zend_Db_Select object.
     */
    public function join($name, $cond, $cols = self::SQL_WILDCARD, $schema = null)
    {
        return $this->joinInner($name, $cond, $cols, $schema);
    }
```

Here is the comment block from from()

```
/**
     * Adds a FROM table and optional columns to the query.
     *
     * The first parameter $name can be a simple string, in which case the
     * correlation name is generated automatically.  If you want to specify
     * the correlation name, the first parameter must be an associative
     * array in which the key is the correlation name, and the value is
     * the physical table name.  For example, array('alias' => 'table').
     * The correlation name is prepended to all columns fetched for this
     * table.
     *
     * The second parameter can be a single string or Zend_Db_Expr object,
     * or else an array of strings or Zend_Db_Expr objects.
     *
     * The first parameter can be null or an empty string, in which case
     * no correlation name is generated or prepended to the columns named
     * in the second parameter.
     *
     * @param  array|string|Zend_Db_Expr $name The table name or an associative array
     *                                         relating correlation name to table name.
     * @param  array|string|Zend_Db_Expr $cols The columns to select from this table.
     * @param  string $schema The schema name to specify, if any.
     * @return Zend_Db_Select This Zend_Db_Select object.
     */
```

Maybe try something like this instead:

```
 $select = $this->_db->select()
 //FROM table procurement_tbltenderevaluationcriteria AS evaluationcriteria, SELECT FROM
 //COLUMNS ScoringCriteriaID and ScoringCriteriaWeight
 ->from(array('evaluationcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderevaluationcriteria'),
 array('ScoringCriteriaID','ScoringCriteriaWeight'))
 //JOIN TABLE procurement_tbltenderscoringcriteria AS scoringcriteria WHERE 
 //TenderId FROM TABLE scoringcriteria == TenderId FROM TABLE evaluationcriteria
 ->join(array('scoringcriteria' => 'procurement_tbltenderscoringcriteria'),
                 'scoringcriteria.TenderId=evaluationcriteria.TenderId')
 //JOIN TABLE procurement_tbltenderapplications AS tenderapplications
 ->join(array('tenderapplications' => 'procurement_tbltenderapplications'))
 //JOIN TABLE tblsupplier AS tendersupplier WHERE TenderInvitationContractorID FROM TABLE 
 // tenderapplications == UserID FROM TABLE tendersupplier
 ->join(array('tendersupplier' => 'tblsupplier'),
   'tenderapplications.TenderInvitationContractorID=tendersupplier.UserID');
```

[you may also need to alter your select() definition to allow joins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.advanced.usage):

```
//this will lock the tables to prevent data corruption
$this->_db->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITHOUT_FROM_PART)->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE);
```

I hope I'm reading your intent correctly,  this should get you closer if not all the way there. (one hint, use shorter aliases...)